# Hide a UITableView of a UIScrollview on a button click in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xcode4

I have a UITableView with some data in  -(void)ViewDidLoad. So it appears accordingly. But when I click a button then my tableview should be hidden and I should load a UIlabel with some text.

But for me  on button click empty tableview with some rows is loading. I should avoid it. How can I do it?

Here is my code

```
 -(void)ViewDidLoad {
 tableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,380,320,200)  style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];  

   }
     -(void)DatePickerDoneClick:(id)sender {
       [tableview setHidden:YES];
       displayError  =[[UILabel alloc]init];
        [displaytError setFrame:CGRectMake(20,400,320,100)];
        displayError.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
        displayError.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        displayError.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Not found"];
        [self.view addSubview:displayError];
    }
```

Could not get where I'm going wrong?

Comment: [tableview setHidden:YES]; correct this line and test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide Table View you can use

```
myTableView.hidden = YES;
```

or

```
[mtTableView setHidden:YES];
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: You can try removeFromSuperview.

Comment: You need to set Break Point and check if control is redirected to -(void)DatePickerDoneClick:(id)sender or not.

Answer (score 0):

if `tableview.hidden = YES;`  is not doing the job

try the next code:

```
[self.tableview removeFromSuperView];
```